# Importing dozens of xls files into Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet that has 5 different tabs. I would like to create this spreadsheet in access represented by 5 different tables.

My first attempt at this is to import in the files. I have the following code

```
Function ImportFiles()
Dim myfile
Dim myDir


mypath = "C:\Data\Dashboard\"
myDir = Directory
myfile = Dir(mypath & "*.xlsx")
While myfile <> ""
Debug.Print "importing" & myfile
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "Data", myfile, True
myfile = Dir()
Wend

End Function
```

I have five tables in my access database. Do I need to write some excel vba to create 5 files that strips out each of the 5 tabs and then import those 5 tabs into the corresponding tables within my access database? Or is there any way to adapt my above code to put the 1st tab of data within each sheet into the first table, the second tab into the 2nd table etc ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code previously written : http://www.accessmvp.com/kdsnell/EXCEL_Import.htm#ImpAllWktsSepTbl

Comment: Not sure if this suits my needs. I have several folders, with dozens of excel files in each folder. I need to select all the folders, and cycle through every file. Every file will have 5 tabs that needs to go into its corresponding access table. Not sure I see an example on  your link that covers such criteria ?

Comment: Some of the topics covered over there are : Import Data from All EXCEL Files in a single Folder via TransferSpreadsheet (VBA), Import Data from Specific Worksheets in All EXCEL Files in a single Folder via TransferSpreadsheet (VBA), Import Data from All Worksheets in a single EXCEL File into One Table via TransferSpreadsheet (VBA), Import Data from All Worksheets in a single EXCEL File into Separate Tables via TransferSpreadsheet (VBA).... Check the link it might get you started.